# select onchange tag does not run my Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, django, html-select

I have the following code:

JS:

```
        function updateLink()
        {
                var selType = document.getElementByID("Types");
                var selLen = document.getElementByID("Length");
                var selLoc = document.getElementByID("Location");
                var selMan = document.getElementByID("Manufacturer");

                var test = document.getElementByID("test");
                test.innerHTML="Test";

                var selectedType = (selType.options[selType.selectedIndex].text);
                var selectedLength = (selLen.options[selLen.selectedIndex].text);
                var selectedLocation = (selLoc.options[selLoc.selectedIndex].text);
                var selectedManufacturer = (selMan.options[selMan.selectedIndex].text);
                document.getElementById("apply").href="myURL?typeName="+selectedType+"length="+selectedLength+"location="+selectedLocation+"manufacturer="+selectedManufacturer;
        }
</script>
```

and HTML

```
 <div id="filterdiv" class="dark">
                <center><h3 id="test">Filters</h3></center>
                <br>
                <center>Type</center>
                <select id="Types" onchange="updateLink()">
                <option>All</option>
                {% for types in TypesList %}
                <option>{{types}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>

                <center>Inspection Period</center>
                <select id="Inspection Period">
                <option>All</option>
                {% for inspections in InspectionList %}
                <option>{{inspections}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>

                <center>Length</center>
                <select id="Length">
                <option>All</option>
                {% for lengths in LengthList %}
                <option>{{lengths}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>

                <center>Location</center>
                <select id="Location">
                <option>All</option>
                {% for locations in LocationList %}
                <option>{{locations}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                </select>
                <br>
                <br>

                <center>Manufacturer</center>
                <select id="Manufacturer">
                <option>All</option>
                {% for manufacturers in ManufacturerList %}
                <option>{{manufacturers}}</option>
                {%endfor%}
                </select>


                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="" id="apply"><button onclick="updatelist()">Apply Filter (TODO)</button></a>
                <a href="http://myURL"><button>Reset Filters</button></a>

 </div>
```

It's a list of select boxes with options taken from my Django models to filter a list in another div. On pressing my button I am redirected to the same URL, no parameters attached. And my test string to change the title also doesn't change anything. So I suspect that my JS code is never triggered. Can anyone help me out here?

I'm aware that my onchange only applies to the Types select box. This code is incomplete. I was testing using the Types box.

myURL is a substitute for my local address which I am hosting this on at the moment.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. Your comments combined made me realise that I had capitalised the D in ID. So I had getElementByID instead of getElementById. How embarrassing!

Comment: @epascarello good catch ! Indeed, JS is case sensitive. `getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed the user who answered this for me has deleted their comments. The answer is a simple syntax error. I had capitalised both letters in ID for GetElementById. A lesson in syntax and case sensitivity!

Answer (score 0):

replace this fragment :

```html
<br>
                <br>
                <a href="" id="apply"><button onclick="updatelist()">Apply Filter (TODO)</button></a>
                <a href="http://myURL"><button>Reset Filters</button></a>
```

this :

```html
 <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="updatelist()">
```